# Присвоению массиву другой массив

Tags: c++

Нужно массиву double а[n] присвоить массив double b[n]. Как реализовать? Без цикла.

Comment: Вот, граждане. Учитесь, как надо задавать вопросы. Коротко и по существу.

Comment: А какого типа элементы массива?

Comment: pavel, в любом случае лишним не будет. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно использовать std::memcpy, которая скорей всего будет выполнена аппаратно (без циклов).

Comment: А есть другие способы?

Comment: Использовать [`vector<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) вместо массивов, например

Comment: Можно использовать указатели.

Comment: std::copy(begin(b),end(b),begin(a));   :D

Comment: @Qwertiy С++11 смотри дополнения по шаблону `template< class T2, size_t N >
void swap( T2 (&a)[N], T2 (&b)[N]);` оно копирует как есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy сорян, в этом же файле потом что-то редактировал видимо. Это не рабочий вариант к сожалению.

Comment: @pavel, а, ясно... Я что-то невнимательно рассмотрел вывод и показалось, что работает, хотя по ощющениям не должен :) А swap можно в ответ запостить.

Answer (score 3):

Голые массивы в С++ являются *некопируемыми* объектами. Они не копируются ни при инициализации, ни через присваивание. (На массивы, обернутые в классы и копируемые неявно и опосредованно вместе с классом, это ограничение не распространяется.)

Поэтому *присвоить* массив `double а[n]` массиву `double b[n]` у вас никак не получится. Либо явный цикл, либо скрытый цикл, типа `memcpy`, `std::copy` и т.п.

---

Разумеется настоящие "кул хацк0ры" не удержатся от соблазна предложить такое решение

```
int main() 
{
  const unsigned N = 100;
  double a[N] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  double b[N];

  struct S
  {
    double a[N];
  };

  *(S *) b = *(S *) a;
}
```

но с точки зрения языка С++ такой код нарушает правила aliasing и его поведение не определено.

Comment: а чем такая реализация лучше чем лобовое копирование? Тут вопрос именно указатели обменять...

Comment: @pavel: О какие таких "указателях" и о каком "лобовом копировании" вы говорите? В вопросе речь идет от массивах вида `double а[n]`. Никаких указателей тут и в помине нет. (К тому же вышеприведенный хак - это и есть "лобовое копирование" целого массива, выполненное одним оператором присваивания.)

Comment: @AnTstandswithRussia а можете объяснить ваш код, не понятно что за второй * первый, вроде как, разыменование

Answer (score 2):

Внимание, этот код работает только для массивов, но не для указателей:

```
memcpy(b, a, sizeof a);
```

https://ideone.com/gaTiyU

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  const unsigned N = 8;

  double a[N] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  double b[N];

  memcpy(b, a, sizeof a);

  for (unsigned q=0; q<N; ++q)
    printf("%lf ", b[q]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с С++11 стандарта появилась новая реализация `std::swap`

```
template< class T2, size_t N >
void swap( T2 (&a)[N], T2 (&b)[N]);
```

Применение:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {4,5,6};
swap(a,b);
```

Важно, внутри всё равно будет полноценное копирование за `O(n)`.

Из плюсов данного метода - можно использовать и для указателей.

[ссылка](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Comment: А как для указателей, указатели же под этот шаблон не подойдут?

Comment: @Qwertiy подойдут под стандартный `template< class T >
void swap( T& a, T& b );`

Comment: Но в таком случае поменяются местами указатели, а не массивы...

Comment: @Qwertiy а внешне разница какая? Всякие memcpy просто скопируют не то что надо.

Comment: Внешне будет разница, если это не единственный экземпляр указателя. memcpy скопирует нормально, если правильно указать размер, а иметь указатель и не знать число элементов - это уже само по себе плохая идея :)